# ExtJS - sencha app build dependency error

Tags: build, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to extend a third party class. The code is something like this. Note I'm specifying where to load `openGL.view`.

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'openGL.view': 'C:/Users/«username»/Documents/third-party/openGL/view/'
});

Ext.define('myOpenGL.view.Qxga',{
    extend: 'openGL.view.Uxga',
    alias: 'widget.qxga',
    itemId: 'qxga',
    requires: [
            'openGL.view.Uxga',
            'myOpenGL.view.QxgaController'
    ],
    controller: 'QxgaController'
});
```

When I build it, I get errors like this:

```
[ERR] Failed to resolve dependency openGL.view.Uxga for file myOpenGL.view.Qxga
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : openGL.view.Uxga
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 6 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\«username»\Applications\Sencha\Cmd\5.1.0.26\plugins\ext\current\plugin.xml:403: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\«username»\Documents\workspace\openGL\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\«username»\Documents\workspace\openGL\.sencha\app\init-impl.xml:303: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : openGL.view.Uxga
```

Some questions:

- Why isn't it finding `openGL.view.Uxga`?
- I've read about modifying `build-impl.xml`, but with various degrees of success. What would I have to do, and is there a way to do the same without having to modify the file? Say some kind of override or command line parameter?
- If there is a way to do this using `setPath`, the `third-party` directory may not be in the same place. Is there a way to include a Windows environment variable or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha Cmd doesn't know about the `Ext.Loader.setPath` call, Cmd doesn't execute the JavaScript. Instead, in your `app.json` you can add `C:/Users/«username»/Documents/third-party` to the `classpath` config. `classpath` is a comma-delimited (I think it may even be able to be an array these days) list of paths Cmd will use to inspect the files within it to search for Ext JS classes (or via certain comment tags like @require and @class).

```
"classpath": "app,C:/Users/«username»/Documents/third-party"
```

Comment: Thank you. `myOpenGL` is actually a package which is trying to extend `openGL` as used in an app. It seems to be outputting app-related errors when they should be package-related. I will re-ask something more focused in a different question.